# Extract embedded files from doc using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using the poi library to deal with the MS files. To extract the embedded ole object for docx, xlsx and pptx, I use method:`PackagePart pp = src.getAllEmbedds()` But for the old format of MS files like doc, xls and ppt, there is no such method. So I am using the extractor: `POITextExtractor[] embeddedExtractors =
                ExtractorFactory.getEmbededDocsTextExtractors(oleTextExtractor);` But this can only extract the text not the whole file.
Can anyone help me with extracting doc, ppt and xls files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OLE2** files include most **Microsoft Office** files such as `XLS`, `DOC`, and `PPT` as well as `MFC` serialization API based file formats. **Office OpenXML Format** is the new standards based **XML** file format found in **Microsoft Office 2007** and **2008**. This includes `XLSX`, `DOCX` and `PPTX`.

For each **MS Office** application there exists a component module that attempts to provide a common high level **Java** api to both **OLE2** and **OOXML** document formats.

See

- [**Apache POI - POIFS - Documents embeded in other documents**](http://poi.apache.org/poifs/embeded.html)
- [**Busy Developers' Guide to HSLF drawing layer**](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/how-to-shapes.html#OLE)
- [**How to extract misc embedded data from a ppt file**](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hslf/examples/DataExtraction.java)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFObjectData;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentEntry;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.Entry;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class TestEmbedded {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       String path = "ParentExcel.xls";
       File file = new File(path);

       NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(file);
       HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs.getRoot(), true);

       for (HSSFObjectData obj : wb.getAllEmbeddedObjects()) {
       System.out.println(obj.getDirectory()+"***************HSSFObject data value************"+obj.getOLE2ClassName());
       String oleName = obj.getOLE2ClassName();
       System.out.println("Has directory Entry node"+obj.hasDirectoryEntry());
       DirectoryNode dn = (DirectoryNode)obj.getDirectory();
       Iterator<Entry> ab = dn.getEntries();
       System.out.println("The entries in the directory node are"+dn.getEntries()+"And also the count"+dn.getEntryCount());

       if(oleName.contains("Worksheet")){

          InputStream is ;
          Entry entry = ab.next();
          is = dn.createDocumentInputStream(entry);
          FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("EmbeddedWorkbook.xlsx");
          IOUtils.copy(is, fos);
          fos.close();
       }


       }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Shwetha Prem. My requirement is same, only difference what if file comes from UI side as multipart file you know, any sugggestion. And one more thing the file is doc/docx embedded in excel' cell

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFObjectData;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DirectoryNode;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentEntry;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.Entry;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;


public class TestEmbedded {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       String path = "DummyParent.xls";
       File file = new File(path);
       POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(file));
       HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs.getRoot(), true);

       for (HSSFObjectData obj : wb.getAllEmbeddedObjects()) {
       System.out.println(obj.getDirectory()+"***************HSSFObject data value************"+obj.getOLE2ClassName());
       String oleName = obj.getOLE2ClassName();
       System.out.println("Has directory Entry node"+obj.hasDirectoryEntry());
       DirectoryNode dn = (DirectoryNode)obj.getDirectory();
       Iterator<Entry> ab = dn.getEntries();
       System.out.println("The entries in the directory node are"+dn.getEntries()+"And also the count"+dn.getEntryCount());

       if(oleName.contains("Worksheet")){
          HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(dn,fs,false);
         int number = hssfWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets();
         System.out.println("The number of sheets in the Embedded excel - xls"+number);
       }


       }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should edit your answer to add any relevant information or comment instead of just commenting on your own answer